# "Play Port" with RTLTcpSource component produces no audio

Tags: redhawksdr

I'm using the component https://github.com/Axios-Engineering/acquisition-components called "RTLTcpSource" from Axios to listen using a RTL2820T USB Dongle. The uses port ComplexIQ_Float plots the port data (and FFT) without any problems.

The data is obviously there but I'm not able to get any sort of audio out. I've tested it against AudioTestSource component, which gives the desired audio output. I have also used DataWriter to output the audio to a file, and then played it through VLC (which plays fine).

I was wondering what sort of adjustments could I make to RTLTcpSource to give it this capability. I have also used the method in this video to try to get an audio output but was not able to play the port data: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wN9p8EjiQs4

I'm using RH 1.84 on CentOS 6.4.

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear from your description what your processing waveform is doing, but you need to have decimation, demod, and data format conversion components in the data path. Something like this:

`RTL TCP -> TuneFilterDecimate -> FM Demod -> TuneFilterDecimate -> Reformat`.

The Reformat component is needed because the Java audio playback is somewhat picky about it's format and sample rate.

You also may find that a later version of the REDHAWK IDE will be more forgiving of your SDR implementation . Some additional capabilities for playing audio data were added since 1.8.4, and some bug fixes were made as well. In particular, 1.9.X makes certain assumptions about your data stream (e.g. sample rate, number of channels) that must be explicitly specified with keywords using 1.8.4.